# Moving to SVG icons - how to separate them from the code?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

SVG icons have some advantages over font icons: they can be scaled to fit a variable-sized container element, and you can theoretically change color of individual paths. I also like the fact that I can easily make them in Inkscape :P

But how do I move the SVG in the CSS file so they can be reused on the same page, like icon fonts, and still benefit from these advantages?

The background property supports SVG, with `background: url(#svg_element)`, but that means I have to put the SVG in the HTML :|
If I put it as a "data" string, how do I change path colors in the same css file?

Comment: you can also put is in a file with anme like svg_element.svg and use it like this  style="background: url(svg_element.svg)"

Comment: That's almost the same using the data url string, but with one extra request for each icon :P

Comment: Can you explain please, what is "how do I change path colors in the same css file"?

Comment: Changing colors of the SVG graphic with "fill" and "stroke" CSS properties

Answer (score 11):

> But how do I move the SVG in the CSS file so they can be reused on the same page, like icon fonts, and still benefit from these advantages?

**With svg templates**

Lets create a svg template.

**Template** (html)

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="hide">
    <circle id="circle-tmp" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Its a template so we hide it. (but still in the DOM)

`.hide { display: none;} //css`

**Use** (html)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="circle-first">
    <use xlink:href="#circle-tmp" />
</svg>
```

This can be reused anywhere on the page.

> how do I change path colors in the same css file?

Easy, just style it!

**css**

```
.circle-first {
    fill: #12bb34;
}
```

Working **example**? 
Here you go: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5oLtv72/1/)

Browser support? Not 100% sure, but svg support in all big browsers: [CanIUseIt](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

Comment: ok so basically all the answers suggest that it's not possible to use svg for styling, at least not yet. I knew about the use thing, but that still doesn't help with moving the icons where they belong - in the css file :(

Answer (score 4):

For in-depth discussion, check out [Sara Soueidan](http://sarasoueidan.com/) who has done a lot of work on SVG. A [recent article/talk she gave](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2014/tips-for-optimising-svg-delivery-for-the-web/) may also have lots of info for you to digest.

[Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) has some very useful things to say too.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SVG as background image then you cannot alter path and fill colors (AFAIK). However, you can use white SVG and background colors to create Metro-ish icons. This is exactly what [jQuery Mobile theming system](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/) does.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon-1 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20points%3D%2214%2C5%209%2C5%207%2C0%205%2C5%200%2C5%204%2C8%202.625%2C13%207%2C10%2011.375%2C13%2010%2C8%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.icon-bg-1 {
  background-color: #800080;
}
.icon-bg-2 {
  background-color: #DB7093;
}
.icon-bg-3 {
  background-color: #CD853F;
}
.icon-bg-4 {
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-bg-1"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-bg-2"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-bg-3"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-bg-4"></span>
```

Another option is to use a colored SVG and use [CSS3 hue-rotate filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#funcdef-hue-rotate) to change the color of SVG. This property is not widely supported yet.

Note: Hue rotation only affects "colors"; black, white and gray remain unaffected.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.icon-1 {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FF0000%3B%22%20points%3D%2214%2C5%209%2C5%207%2C0%205%2C5%200%2C5%204%2C8%202.625%2C13%207%2C10%2011.375%2C13%2010%2C8%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.icon-hue-1 {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
     -moz-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
}
.icon-hue-2 {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.icon-hue-3 {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
     -moz-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.icon-hue-4 {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
     -moz-filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-hue-1"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-hue-2"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-hue-3"></span>
<span class="icon icon-1 icon-hue-4"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to preserve the niceties of SVG icons, there is at the moment no alternative to including the `<svg>` in your HTML page.

[Chris Coyier's article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) describes the generally accepted best practice for inclusion. It's something like:

1. Store your SVG icon definitions as `<symbols>`:

   ```
   <svg id='my-icons'>
      <symbol id='icon-puppy'> <!-- puppy icon goes here --> </symbol>
      <symbol id='icon-kitty'> <!-- kitty icon goes here --> </symbol>
   </svg>
   ```
2. When you need to use an icon, reference the icon definition:

   ```
   <svg class='icon'>
      <use xlink:href='#icon-puppy'/>
   </svg>
   ```

[This article](http://danburzo.ro/svg-icon-system/) describes how you might go about including the SVG file in the HTML dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems you wanna keep away `xml` contents of `svg` file from `html`
>   codes.

To meet this, Two scenarios are available to embed `svg` files into the `html`:

1. Using `<object data="~/img/file.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>` element, So `xml` will
   be separated from `html` **==>** the resulted view would be
   combination of `html` and `xml` that can be styled with `css`
   (perhaps a `scoped` one e.g. using `<style scoped="scoped"></style>`
   at the target page).
2. using `<img src="~/img/file.svg"/>` element, So `xml` will be separated
   from `html` **==>** the resulted view would be only `html` and `css`
   can't perform on `xml` contents of `svg` file.

Another way to employ `svg` is to use inline technique, say, using `<svg>` tag so you can use inline stylesheets too for this, **But you wanna separate `xml` from `html` here:)**

For more information:
[Using SVG](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) and [SVG Styling with CSS](http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/).

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with SVG before but not with SVG icons specifically. However based on the knowledge I have and doing some looking around, here is what I came up with (I might not have understood your question fully in that case please post more questions).

> But how do I move the SVG in the CSS file so they can be reused on the same page
>
> but that means I have to put the SVG in the HTML

SVG is basically XML, so not exactly sure why you prefer not to put SVG in HTML file. If you put SVG in HTML file you could just use external or internal CSS to style SVG. Here is a [sample](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/03/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/2/) to just do that.

In HTML file:

```
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" />
```

In a CSS file: (Include CSS file in you HTML file)

```
<style>
circle {
  fill: deepPink;
  transition: fill .3s ease-out;
}

circle:hover {
  fill: #009966;
}
</style>
```

Here is the second option of many other, use `<img/>` tag. Here is an [article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/manipulating-svg-icons-with-simple-css--webdesign-15694) which explains how to use SVG from a separate file using `<img/>`tag. And here is the [code](http://tutsplus.github.io/Styling-Iconic/state/index.html) accompanying it. Also note that it uses jQuery plugin [svginject](https://github.com/wearecube/bower-jquery-svginject).

Here are few other [options](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/03/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/4/) to keep SVG out of HTML and their merits.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do some digging into the [evil-icons](https://github.com/outpunk/evil-icons) project. You'll find out some neat ways of using svg.

Their nicest idea is to merge all of your icons into a single file "sprite.svg". Each of your svg icons needs to be enclosed by a `<symbol>` tag with an id. Then you access it whenever you need through an xlink, as commented in other answers.

By loading the entire sprite.svg you'll gain in load time and neatness.